# How to add multiple field groups to a node

Tags: nodes, entities

I have a node type "Project", and users can add multiple tasks for this Project node. e.g. There is a Project named "Building website", it contains two tasks "Design" and "Code", and every Task has another two fields: time and budget.

The **Field Group** module can solve part of the problem, it can mix multiple fields into one field. But this mixed field amount can only be 1. That means I can only add one Task field in a Project, however I need add unlimited Task field to Project. Do you know any modules can do this job?

Comment: Did you solve it using field group module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Field collection Modules**

Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can be attached.

A field collection is internally represented as an entity, which is embedded in the host entity. Thus, if desired field collections may be viewed and edited separately too.